# Why "daran" and not "darüber"? How to know when to use which?

Tags: preposition

In the following sentence, why do we use "daran" and not "darüber"? How to know when to use which? I thought it should have been "darüber" because there is an "über" in the sentence just before.

> Ich will selbst über mein Leben bestimmen. Was ist so schlimm daran?

Comment: The "über" has **nothing** to do with the "daran". You could replace the statement with any other and it wouldn't change the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common expression:

*Was ist so ... daran?*

It relates back to the **entire sentence**, not only part of it, so it wouldn't make sense to make it *darüber*.

Answer (score 8):

To generalize this:

The preposition to use in German with adjectives like "gut", "schlecht", "schlimm", "großartig" etc. that corresponds with "about" in English is "an".

> Das Gute an der neuen Software ist die leichtere Bedienung.
> An diesem Sommer war schlimm, dass es fast überall Dürren gab.

That's why we also use "daran".

> Wir benutzen eine neue Software, und daran ist manches gut und manches schlecht.
> Es war ein warmer Sommer, was ist daran schlimm?

I guess there's not much point in further going into why we're using that preposition, unless you're a language history buff.